# shared memory after exec()

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, mmap

How can I share memory between the parent and the child if the child has run **exec()** to load another program?

Is it possible using **mmap**?

By now parent and child share memory properly using mmap, but not after **exec** is done

Comment: *after exec is done* - `exec` is not returning.

Comment: I know, but I wonder if parent and resulting process after exec can share memory somehow using mmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shm_open` to open a "named" shared memory block which is identified by a file on the filesystem. Example:
In the parent:

```
int memFd = shm_open("example_memory", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
if (memFd == -1)
{
    perror("Can't open file");
    return 1;
}

int res = ftruncate(memFd, /*size of the memory block you want*/);
if (res == -1)
{
    perror("Can't truncate file");
    return res;
}
void *buffer = mmap(NULL, /*size of the memory block you want*/, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memFd, 0);
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    perror("Can't mmap");
    return -1;
}
```

In the other file:

```
int memFd = shm_open("example_memory", O_RDONLY, 0);
if (memFd == -1)
{
    perror("Can't open file");
    return 1;
}

void *buffer = mmap(NULL, /*size of the memory block you want*/, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, memFd, 0);
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    perror("Can't mmap");
    return -1;
}
```

After these segments of code you can use `buffer` to access the shared memory. (Note: it doesn't need to be `void*`, you can make it a pointer to whatever you intend to store in the shared mem)

Answer (score 6):

> How can I share memory between the parent and the child if the child
>   has run exec() to load another program?

Neither memory mappings created via `mmap()` nor POSIX shared-memory segments obtained via `shm_open()` nor System V shared-memory segments obtained via `shmat()` are preserved across an exec.  That covers all the forms of shared memory I am aware of Linux providing.

It follows that if you want the child to share memory with the parent after an `exec()` then the child must (re)connect to the appropriate shared memory *after* the `exec()`.  Obviously, that means that whatever program is started by the `exec()` must be written to do that.  (Note in particular that on success, the exec-family functions do not return.)

> Is it possible using mmap?

Only if the child re-maps the memory after the `exec()`.

> By now parent and child share memory properly using mmap, but not
>   after exec is done

That is by design.

Comment: @Jogn Bollinger : You wrote: Only if the child re-maps the memory after the exec()..And how can be remmaped using mmap from the child?