# Is it possibility that one shared memory segment will attach multiple time to same parent pid?

Tags: c, linux, memory, ipc

I have created 200 child processes of a parent which communicate through share memory IPC mechanism:

Parent <-> SHM <-> child

But the observation is STRANGE.

I found 4 processes are attached to the same SHM id in which 2 are parent pid and 2 are child pid.(Unexpected Behaviour).
and somewhere 2 processes are attached to one SHM id (Expected behaviour).

Please found below output-

```
-bash-4.2# grep 123076652 /proc/*/maps
/proc/27750/maps:7f1323576000-7f1323577000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 123076652  /SYSV2c006eff (deleted)    
/proc/27750/maps:7f1323676000-7f1323677000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 123076652  /SYSV2c006eff (deleted)
/proc/27827/maps:7f87ac3c0000-7f87ac3c1000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 123076652  /SYSV2c006eff (deleted)
/proc/28090/maps:7f9d33b8b000-7f9d33b8c000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 123076652  /SYSV2c006eff (deleted)
```

As we can easily see that PID-27750(Parent) attached two times to one segment.

How is it possible ?
Is it Centos Bug?

Comment: I think you'll have to post your code for this. What you've shown is the end result. But, not how you got there. It is unlikely to be a Centos (i.e. kernel) bug. What does `ipcs` say?

Comment: Hi Craig .I found the problem i was using same id to generate the ftok() key for two child processes.Can you please explain how much maximum unique keys can be generated using ftok().AFAIK only last low 8 bits are significant. Can we use can we use 2 byte integer like "300" to generate the key .What is the chance for keys duplicate here?Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the problem i was using same id to generate the `ftok()` key for two child processes.

A `key_t` is 32 bits, and can have *any* value we want.

`ftok` is just a "convenience" function to generate a unique `key_t` value to be used in a call to `shmget` (See below).

If we use `IPC_PRIVATE` for this `key_t` value, we get a private descriptor that any child of a *single* parent process can use. It shows up in `ipcs` as a `key_t` of 0, with a unique `shmid` [which is like a file descriptor].

So, if have a single parent and we're *just* doing `fork`, we can use this, because the children will inherit this from the parent. This is the preferred method. So, in this case, `ftok` isn't needed.

With private keys, when all attached processes terminate, the shared areas are automatically removed by the kernel.

If we use a non-zero `key_t` value, we are creating a *permanent* area. It will remain (with the data still there).

To remove this, the final process (i.e. the *parent* process) must do `shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL)` for all `shmid` gotten from the `shmget` calls.

If the parent process dies *before* doing this, the area remains. Such areas will still show up in `ipcs`

---

Here is some sample code that illustrates the use of `IPC_PRIVATE`. It *can* be adapted to use a non-zero `key_t` value, but for your application, that may not be warranted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NCHILD      200
#define SIZE        4096

// child process control
typedef struct {
    int tsk_cldidx;                     // child index
    int tsk_shmid;                      // shmid for process
    pid_t tsk_pid;                      // pid of process
    void *tsk_shmadr;                   // address of attached area
} tsk_t;

tsk_t cldlist[NCHILD];

void
dofork(int cldidx)
{
    tsk_t *tskself = &cldlist[cldidx];

    do {
        tskself->tsk_pid = fork();

        // parent
        if (tskself->tsk_pid != 0)
            break;

        // detach from all areas that are not ours
        for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < NCHILD;  ++cldidx) {
            tsk_t *tsk = &cldlist[cldidx];
            if (tsk->tsk_cldidx != tskself->tsk_cldidx)
                shmdt(tsk->tsk_shmadr);
        }

        // do something useful ...

        exit(0);
    } while (0);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int cldidx;
    tsk_t *tsk;

    // create private shared memory ids for each child
    for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < NCHILD;  ++cldidx) {
        tsk = &cldlist[cldidx];
        tsk->tsk_cldidx = cldidx;
        tsk->tsk_shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,SIZE,0);
        tsk->tsk_shmadr = shmat(tsk->tsk_shmid,NULL,0);
    }

    // start up all children
    for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < NCHILD;  ++cldidx)
        dofork(cldidx);

    // do something useful with children ...

    // wait for all children
    while (wait(NULL) >= 0);

    // remove all segments
    // NOTE: with IPC_PRIVATE, this may not be necessary -- it may happen
    // automatically when we exit
    for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < NCHILD;  ++cldidx) {
        tsk = &cldlist[cldidx];
        shmctl(tsk->tsk_shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

If we have separate programs that have *no* parent/child relationship, we need a non-zero `key_t`. It can be hard to generate a unique `key_t` that does not collide/conflict with another, possibly from a totally unrelated group of programs (e.g. another user)

> Can you please explain how much maximum unique keys can be generated using ftok().
>
> AFAIK only last low 8 bits are significant. Can we use can we use 2 byte integer like "300" to generate the key . What is the chance for keys duplicate here?

For a given [existing] file and *eight* bit `proj_id`, there are [as you've noticed] only 256 unique keys that can be generated. We'd need a *different* file argument to get the next 256.

It might be better to dispense with `ftok` altogether [I've *never* used it when using `shmget`]. I've done `0xAA000000` as the base `key_t` value. I've replaced the zeroes with whatever unique sub-key value I need (there are ~24 million possible combinations).

---

If we control all programs that will access the shared memory areas, it isn't necessary to have multiple areas.

It may be sufficient, and *more* desirable to have a *single* shared memory area. In that case, we only do *one* `shmget` and *one* `shmat`. Then, `ftok(myfile,0)` could produce a nice key.

If the size of the needed to communicate with a child is (e.g.) a page (`PER_CHILD = 4096`), and we have `NCHILD` children to create, we can just create a single area of `TOTAL_SIZE = PER_CHILD * NCHILD` in size. Then, for a given child X, its area pointer is `shmaddr + (X * PER_CHILD)`

---

**UPDATE:**

> Can I use IPC_CREAT flag and do exec() call to child?

I think what you mean is using the non-zero key with `shmget` in conjunction with this.

An exec call will close any *mappings*: [shared memory after exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190685/shared-memory-after-exec/48191050#48191050)

It will also close the file descriptor returned by `shmget` [or `shm_open`].

So, using the non-zero key is the only [practical] way to ensure that it works across `execvp` et al.

> Will it cause any problem. AFAIK if we use exec() then a process will have a different address space. Will it cause any problem?

The child *program* will have to (re)establish its own mapping via `shmget` and `shmat`.

But, if we use `shm_open` [instead of `shmget`], we *can* keep the file descriptor open *if* we use `fcntl` to clear the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag on the descriptor before calling `execvp`.

However, this may be of little use as the child *program* (target of `execvp`) will [probably] not know the file descriptor number that the parent opened with `shm_open`, so it's a bit of a moot point.

Comment: Hi Craig Thanks for your quick help.But i have one more doubt :Can I use IPC_CREAT flag and do exec() call to child? Will it cause any problem.AFAIK if we use exec() then a process will have a different address space. Will it cause any problem?Am very sorry for this silly doubt and also for this much delayed reply.

Comment: Well, don't forget to upvote and accept [one of] the answers ;-)

Comment: Accepted your answer and Thanks for such a detailed explanation.Now i thinks that my problem will be solved and i will use IPC_CREAT with exec().

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: Yes of course. You have the evidence right there in your question.

How does it happen? If you call `mmap()` on the same file multiple times it maps it multiple times.

To avoid that happening the answer is: Don't do that.

I'm purely guessing but my bet is that one of your `fork()` calls failed and you never did any error checking, and the code continued on to execute the child code in the parent process. That would explain having two maps on one PID.

Comment: Thanks Zan for your quick help. One more doubt can i use ftok() with id value more than 255 to generate a key. As according to man page it is taking arguments as int but it is also mentioned that only lower 8 bits are significant. If i use values for id like 258 or more than that....Is there are any chances for generate duplicate key by ftok().??Please help.